# Finding a UNC Path on another server?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vbscript, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm need of some way of finding the UNC Path of a share via a script or command line or even a custom created program. I'm trying to automate deletion of users and the setup is a bit complicated.

Home folders are set up like this:

We create a folder on a Disk on a fileserver.
When this folder is created, a share is automatically created on a lower level
Then the DFS Links are set up towards the newly created share.

Now, when deleting a user, I could just delete the DFS Folder, meaning that the target folder is the one being deleted. But since it's a share, that cannot happen.

SO, I need to find out where this share is actually pointing at and then programtically delete THAT folder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/224901-how-can-i-get-names-shared-folders-host) is a post on enumerating the shares on a given host using C#.

It uses the [Win32_Share WMI class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28VS.85%29.aspx), which has the disk path of the share as one of its properties. It might be possible to use that class to search for a particular share, given a UNC path. Or if you knew the name of the share you can simply loop through the enumeration results until you find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past using the native call to netapi32.dll.

The method is called [NetShareDel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525386(VS.85).aspx) and there is some sample code [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetShareDel.html). Remember to release your memory properly.